# Enzyme testing Reactjs component that uses global jQuery object

Tags: jquery, reactjs, enzyme

I'm integrating Reactjs incrementally into a web app frontend built with HTML5 and jQuery. My react component uses global jQuery object (for AJAX and some animations here and there) that would be available when the react component javascript is loaded.

Now, when I try to `mount()` this component for testing with Enzyme, it get following error

```
 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How do I make `jQuery` object available for the mounted component?

[Testing a React component that uses jQuery & window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082197/testing-a-react-component-that-uses-jquery-window-object) is a similar question with 0 answers...

I'm willing to update the component code if necessary.

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit

Sample code of my component

```
  import React from 'react';

  export default class MySimpleComponent extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
        var add_btn = this.refs.btn_add;
        (function ($) {
           $(add_btn).click(function (ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
              console.log('button was clicked');
           });
        })(jQuery);
     }

     render() {
        return (
           <div className="wrap">
              <form action="/">
                 <input type="text" name="myinput" value="" />
                 <button className="button" ref="btn_add">New Record</button>
              </form>
           </div>
        );
     }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post the component code please

Comment: @spirift I've added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you might be able to do this with [jsdom](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md). You have to setup some globals as they say in the readme. Just add in `global.jQuery = () => {};` as well.

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

global.document = jsdom('');
global.jQuery = () => {};
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

I have not had a chance to try out the above. However I would not recommend this as a sustainable solution. A much better approach would be to drop jQuery. Here is your component refactored without it.

```
  import React from 'react';

  export default class MySimpleComponent extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     clickHanlder(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       console.log('button was clicked');
     }

     render() {
        return (
           <div className="wrap">
              <form action="/">
                 <input type="text" name="myinput" value="" />
                 <button className="button" onClick={this.clickHanlder}>New Record</button>
              </form>
           </div>
        );
     }
  }
```

As you can see it's not that different. You can attach the event handlers directly to the elements, for me this makes the code easier to read and see where the action is, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've actually modified a small part of my component to use native event handling and it has eliminated the error. I think I will eventually remove all jQuery code from my component and try to incorporate some other way of animating elements.. CSS transitions may be.

Comment: Check out [react velocity](https://github.com/twitter-fabric/velocity-react) or [react motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion)

Comment: What does `global.jQuery = () => {};` do?  It looks like you are setting jQuery to an empty object but why?

Comment: It's setting jQuery to be a none operational function, or a no-op. This way when the code being tested calls jQuery is does NOT throw an error about jQuery not being a function.